# How to convert IEnumerable<XElement> to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing

I have a String that contain some data that i want to manipulate, so i am sending it to a function that does this manipulation.

I want to return that string after he get manipulates in the function.

What i manage to to is to return `IEnumerable<XElement>` from that function that contains the right content after he get manipulate

I tried to return `xmlElements.ToString();` from the function but it contained some weird string and not the actual string it self.

*renderedOutput= a string in XML structure*

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(renderedOutput);
IEnumerable<XElement> xmlElements = xml.Descendants();
```

Then i am sending it to that function (that changes some values)

```
 xmlElements = SetAdditionalData(xmlElements, docIDs[i], i, orderID);// This is the place where i want to get a String in XML strcture
```

This just an example of what the function does:

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> SetAdditionalData(IEnumerable<XElement> xmlElements, string docID, int i, string orderID)
{
    foreach (var el in xmlElements)
    {
        // set country name from country iso
        if (el.Name == "Country")
        {                                      
            var isoC = el.Value.ToString().Trim();
            if (isoC != string.Empty)
            {
                RegionInfo isoCode = new RegionInfo(isoC);
                el.SetValue(isoCode.DisplayName);
            }
            continue;                    
        }
    }

    return xmlElements;  // tried to return xmlElements.ToSting(), but it didn't returned the right data
}
```

**I am trying to achieve that:**

xmlElements will contain the string after manipulates - meaning after `SetAdditionalData()` set some additional data

Comment: @Henk I am expecting `XML string`

Comment: @Henk, ask i mentioned- i am looking for `xmlElements.ToSting()` which don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
return String.Concat(xmlElements.Select(element => element.OuterXml));
```

For what it's worth I would just return the elements - that way the function is only doing one thing, modifying the elements. Then if the caller needs a string it can convert the elements to a string.

Comment: I am getting this error: `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: there is no property OuterXml on the [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx). To get the XML from IEnumerable<XElement> just call something like this:  `var xml = string.Concat(xmlElements)` or `var xml = string.Join("\r\n", xmlElements)`

Comment: `XElement `inherits `OuterXml` from `XmlNode`.

Comment: this works for me, return String.Concat(xmlElements.Select(element => element.ToString()));

Comment: `XmlElement` inherits from `XmlNode`, whereas `XElement` inherits from `XNode` (which doesn't have the OuterXml property as @chviLadislav points out)

Answer (score 0):

Try options below:
Get the content of the element if the content is text:

```
xmlElements.Value
```

Get the content of the element as XML:

```
xmlElements.InnerXml
```

Get the element and its content as XML:

```
xmlElements.OuterXml
```

Comment: i am getting an error for all those 3 example: `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: Once you iterate over the list in the caller you will get these values. You cannot directly get these values on IEnumearble object. Please reffer to @Scott Hannen post.

Comment: Add this to the top of your file: using System.Linq;

Comment: @Scott Hannen `System.Linq;` is there already - yet the error appear.